# SQL Range of Sequence number records get remaining No

Tags: sql, sql-server

MSSQL Server 8.0
Master Table:

```
BATCHNo　　SEQFrom　　SEQTo   
0001　　　　0001　　　　3000  
0001　　　　3000　　　　5000  
0002　　　　0001　　　　0500
```

Table:

```
RecordID　　BATCHNo　　SEQFrom　　SEQTo   
1　　　　　　0001　　　　0001　　　　0100  
2　　　　　　0001　　　　0102　　　　0202  
3　　　　　　0001　　　　0210　　　　0222
```

I want to know the missing numbers (101,203,204,205,206,207,208,209)
The output:

```
BATCHNo　　SEQ   
0001  　101
0001  　203
0001  　204
0001  　205
0001  　206
0001  　207
0001  　208
0001  　209
```

Comment: Please provide relation between input and output & tag DBMS.

Comment: Do I get this correctly: Between `SEQTo` and **the next** `SEQFrom` is a gap and you need to know the missing numbers? It would be nice to elaborate your question. Reading the magic glass bulb makes me so tired... And please state 1) RDBMS 2) Version 3) expected output 4) Some explanation what you want to achieve.

Comment: And also state that how you want to get t he output e.g. in just a variable or row wise or other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in MsSQL 2012+ as  the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (RecordID INT, BATCHNo VARCHAR(10), SEQFrom VARCHAR(10), SEQTo VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES
(1,'0001', '0001','0100'),  
(2,'0001', '0102','0202'),  
(3,'0001', '0210','0222') 

;WITH Tally
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n AS Number,
        T.BATCHNo
    FROM 
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n),
        (SELECT DISTINCT BATCHNo FROM @Tbl) T
    WHERE 
        ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n < (SELECT MAX(T.SEQTo * 1) FROM @Tbl T)

), Tmp
AS
(
    SELECT  
        *,
        LEAD(T.SEQFrom) OVER (ORDER BY RecordID) NextSEQ
    FROM @Tbl T

)

SELECT
    A.BATCHNo,
    B.Number AS SEQ
FROM 
    Tmp A INNER JOIN 
    Tally B ON B.Number > A.SEQTo AND B.Number < A.NextSEQ AND A.BATCHNo = B.BATCHNo
```

Result:

```
BATCHNo    SEQ
---------- -----------
0001       101
0001       203
0001       204
0001       205
0001       206
0001       207
0001       208
0001       209
```